# Facebook API: How to get the conversion pixel values for an ad

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

How can I read the values for a conversion pixel via Facebook API v2.4?

From what I read (and tried) you can't get it via the `Insights API` and the `Reporting API` is deprecated.

I want to read the following values:

- `actions_28d_click:offsite_conversion.checkout`  - Checkouts
  (Conversion Pixel) [28 Days After Clicking]
- `actions_28d_view:offsite_conversion.checkout` - Checkouts
  (Conversion Pixel) [28 Days After Viewing]
- `actions_28d_click:offsite_conversion.registration` - Registrations
  (Conversion Pixel) [28 Days After Clicking]
- `actions_28d_view:offsite_conversion.registration` - Registrations
  (Conversion Pixel) [28 Days After Viewing]

Comment: Which values would you like to read from the pixel?

Comment: @Roemer, I edited the question. If you need more details please ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this might help you:
https://www.facebookmarketingdevelopers.com/samples/adsreporting

You need to query the Insights-API. That sample script above is retrieving values for the "28d-click"-attribution window.
You need to change or extend the if-clause and the params-dict accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarifying.

No, it's not possible to retrieve these values using the Public API. These values are reported by Power Editor and Ads Manager only.

Comment: Thanks, but are there any plans to make that data available with the public API?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.